# mongo searching for a large number of mongo ids

Tags: php, mongodb

```
    //Search results for mongo_ids  
    foreach ($results->response->docs as $doc)
    {
        $mongo_ids[] = new MongoId($doc->mongo_id);
    }
    $search['_id'] = array('$in' => $mongo_ids);
```

If I have 100's of mongo ids in the search result...will the query on mongo be really slow?

Answer (score 2):

The `_id` field is indexed by default so an IN query should be very fast, even if its matching many records.

I do the same sort of thing with hundreds of IDs and never have any performance issues.

Comment: what if I have thousands of documents in my collection? would it be slow ?

Comment: hundreds is OK. Thousands is almost OK. hundreds of thousands won't. I had the same issue with a database of ~300K documents and even with the index, it's horribly slow especially when the list of IDS to match is long

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's going to be more and more problematic as the number of id's you use in the `$in` query grows. We experienced some significant increase in query execution time with arrays of few thousand id's.

You can see how many documents are being scanned while executing your query by using [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Use%7B%7Bexplain%7D%7D.) function in MongoDB shell (or using wrapped queries):

`{"$query" : {"foo" : "bar"}, "$explain" : true}`

Number of scanned documents should be as close to the number of returned documents as possible.

Just a general note that might be useful for others - sometimes you don't really need the `$in` query at all. If you reverse the one to many relation you can simplify the query. For example, if you want to find songs that are liked by the user, instead of having following structure:

```
user :
{
    'likes' : [
        ObjectId(song_id1),
        ObjectId(song_id2),
        ...
    ]
}
```

you can have:

```
song :
{
    'likedBy' : [
        ObjectId(user_id1),
        ObjectId(user_id2),
        ...
    ]
}
```

then you can just query for songs for which `{'likedBy' : ObjectId(yourUserId)}` (MongoDB will look for the id in the array). Of course it depends on the situation, and this example is trivial, but sometimes you can speed up query a lot by reversing the relation, and maybe adding some data redundancy.